# Mongoose : populate after save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a project where I'm using the **MERN** stack along with **Redux**.

When I'm fetching normal data with a `get` request, everything works perfectly after a clean page refresh because I can populate the query with **referenced data**, but when I'm saving for example **new data**, in the `response json` I'm only receiving the raw data of `ObjectID` and not the referenced data with it.

**I believe I will need to populate the saved response with a new query or something similar to `.populate` in order to get the referenced data but I have no idea to do so.**

I already tried something I've read here such as `execPopulate` on `save()` but didn't work.

Example of **response JSON** with `post` request :

```
{
  "suggestion": "61cb83b1e7a2d3469d2adc9e",
  "user": "61b4a9253f40b9c22969d11f",
  "content": "testing content",
  "rating": 3,
  "spoiler": false,
  "_id": "61d7df8c5883e282879c6fb9",
  "date": "2022-01-07T06:37:00.196Z",
  "upvotes": [],
  "__v": 0
}
```

Example of **response** with `get` request that **I would want to receive in `save` too**, notice the fields `suggestion` & `user` are populated :

```
 {
    "_id": "61d7df8c5883e282879c6fb9",
    "suggestion": {
      "_id": "61cb83b1e7a2d3469d2adc9e",
      "title": "Beyond",
      "suggestion_type": "Book",
      "image": "91b2d138-883a-4fab-8e0c-a554dd466349.png",
      "token": "LSSRuE"
    },
    "user": {
      "_id": "61b4a9253f40b9c22969d11f",
      "username": "test_user",
      "avatar": "https://i.pinimg.com/2349087qsbjkqsbd.jpg"
    },
    "content": "Testing content",
    "rating": 3,
    "spoiler": false,
    "date": "2022-01-07T06:37:00.196Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
```

**Save** route :

```
router.post(
  '/:token/reviews',
  [auth, [check('rating', 'Rating is required').not().isEmpty()]],
  async (req, res) => {
       
    try {
      const suggestion = await Suggestion.findOne({ token: req.params.token });
       
      const review = await Review.find({
        suggestion: suggestion.id,
      });          

      const newReview = new Review({
        content: req.body.content,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        spoiler: req.body.spoiler,
        user: req.user.id,
        suggestion: suggestion.id,
      });

      await newReview.save();

      res.json(newReview);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);
```

**Get** route :

```
router.get('/:token/reviews/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const suggestion = await Suggestion.findOne({
      token: req.params.token,
    });
    const review = await Review.find({
      suggestion: suggestion.id,
    })
      .populate('user', ['avatar', 'username', 'id'])
      .populate('suggestion', [
        'id',
        'token',
        'title',
        'image',
        'suggestion_type',
      ]);

    if (!review) {
      res
        .status(404)
        .json({ msg: 'No reviews found for the specified suggestion' });
    }

    res.json(review);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    if (error.kind === 'ObjectId') {
      res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Review not found' });
    }
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Reviews model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  suggestion: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'suggestion' },

  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },

  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

  content: {
    type: String,
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
  },
  spoiler: { type: Boolean, default: 0 },

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('review', ReviewSchema);
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

I added this line `await newReview.populate('user');` after   `await newReview.save();`

From the official documentation :
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_an_existing_mongoose_document

**Populating an existing document**

If you have an existing mongoose document and want to populate some of its paths, you can use the Document#populate() method.

```
const person = await Person.findOne({ name: 'Ian Fleming' });

person.populated('stories'); // null

// Call the `populate()` method on a document to populate a path.
await person.populate('stories');

person.populated('stories'); // Array of ObjectIds
person.stories[0].name; // 'Casino Royale'
```

Comment: There's also `mongoose-autopopulate` library to do this automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by chaining `populate` after `findOne` using dot notation. 
ex.

```
const person = await Person.findOne({
  name: 'Ian Fleming'
}).populate('stories');
```

bonus: for field selection, you can use mongo syntax.
ex.

```js
populate('stories', { title: 1, author: 1 });
```

will return an object populated with those fields only including _id.
Refer to [mongodb docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) for more